# how to use background url to div with static with s3 in dajngo

Tags: django

i have

```
<div class="p-5 back-image  corner-radius" >{{obj.app_name}}</div>
```

for this i need to add css like this

```
.back-image {
        background: url("/static/boss/slider-2.jpg") 50% fixed;
    }
```

this is working fine when local host but
now i am using s3 bucket to to server static files for this

```
background: url("/static/boss/slider-2.jpg") 50% fixed; // not working still picking localhost

background: url("'{{static}}'/boss/slider-2.jpg") 50% fixed; // not working

background: url("'{{STATIC_URL}}'/boss/slider-2.jpg") 50% fixed; // not working
```

how to fix this , is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make use of inline css for your case

```
<div class="p-5 corner-radius" style="background: url('{% static 'boss/slider-2.jpg' %}') 50% fixed;">{{obj.app_name}}</div>
```